# how to query in oracle where string like 'XXX-XX' i.e. string contains (hyphen)

Tags: oracle, sql-like

1. select caseid, indcase from casemt where indcase like '%19663-01%'
2. select caseid, indcase from casemt where indcase like '%19663%'

Query1 returns 0 records. while query2 returns multiple records where one of the record's **indcase** is equal to 19663-01

so the question is why query1 is returning 0 records despite the fact that **indcase = 19663-01** exist in oracle table

Comment: Are you sure there isn't any hidden text, invisible whitespace or other characters in the `indcase` column? What do you get if you query the `LEN()` (and binary length, if possible) of the values?

Comment: there exists invisible whitespace in the indcase column.
Saved the day. Thanks @Dai

Comment: You may also find that there are at least 5 different hyphens in ranges U+2010-U+2014, U+2043 and [other in the punctuation set](https://unicode-table.com/en/sets/punctuation-marks/) which may or may not look similar depending on the font of the output.

Answer (score 1):

You can debug your data:

```sql
SELECT caseid,
       indcase,
       DUMP(indcase) AS actual_binary,
       DUMP('19663-01') AS expected_binary
FROM   casemt
WHERE  indcase like '%19663_01%'
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE casemt (caseid, indcase) AS
SELECT 1, '19663-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, CAST(UNISTR('19663\201001') AS VARCHAR2(10)) FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, CAST(UNISTR('19663\201201') AS VARCHAR2(10)) FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, CAST(UNISTR('19663\201301') AS VARCHAR2(10)) FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, CAST(UNISTR('19663\201401') AS VARCHAR2(10)) FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 6, CAST(UNISTR('19663\204301') AS VARCHAR2(10)) FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 7, CAST(UNISTR('19663\FE6301') AS VARCHAR2(10)) FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 8, CAST(UNISTR('19663\FF0D01') AS VARCHAR2(10)) FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 9, CAST(UNISTR('19663\180601') AS VARCHAR2(10)) FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | CASEID | INDCASE | ACTUAL_BINARY | EXPECTED_BINARY |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | 19663-01 | Typ=1 Len=8: 49,57,54,54,51,45,48,49 | Typ=96 Len=8: 49,57,54,54,51,45,48,49 |
> | 2 | 19663‐01 | Typ=1 Len=10: 49,57,54,54,51,226,128,144,48,49 | Typ=96 Len=8: 49,57,54,54,51,45,48,49 |
> | 3 | 19663‒01 | Typ=1 Len=10: 49,57,54,54,51,226,128,146,48,49 | Typ=96 Len=8: 49,57,54,54,51,45,48,49 |
> | 4 | 19663–01 | Typ=1 Len=10: 49,57,54,54,51,226,128,147,48,49 | Typ=96 Len=8: 49,57,54,54,51,45,48,49 |
> | 5 | 19663—01 | Typ=1 Len=10: 49,57,54,54,51,226,128,148,48,49 | Typ=96 Len=8: 49,57,54,54,51,45,48,49 |
> | 6 | 19663⁃01 | Typ=1 Len=10: 49,57,54,54,51,226,129,131,48,49 | Typ=96 Len=8: 49,57,54,54,51,45,48,49 |
> | 7 | 19663﹣01 | Typ=1 Len=10: 49,57,54,54,51,239,185,163,48,49 | Typ=96 Len=8: 49,57,54,54,51,45,48,49 |
> | 8 | 19663－01 | Typ=1 Len=10: 49,57,54,54,51,239,188,141,48,49 | Typ=96 Len=8: 49,57,54,54,51,45,48,49 |
> | 9 | 19663᠆01 | Typ=1 Len=10: 49,57,54,54,51,225,160,134,48,49 | Typ=96 Len=8: 49,57,54,54,51,45,48,49 |

Which, shows that there are multiple different hyphen characters:

- the ACSII character with the character code 45; and
- the characters in the extended character sets with the UTF-8 (hex) codes of:

  - U+1806 (Mongolian Todo Soft Hyphen)
  - U+2010 (Hyphen)
  - U+2012 (Figure Dash)
  - U+2013 (En Dash)
  - U+2014 (Em Dash)
  - U+2043 (Hyphen Bullet)
  - U+FE63 (Small Hyphen-Minus)
  - U+FF0D (Fullwidth Hyphen-Minus)

And your data could be using any of them for a hyphen character.

---

If you want to match them all then you can use:

```sql
SELECT caseid,
       indcase
FROM   casemt
WHERE  TRANSLATE(
         indcase,
         UNISTR('\1806\2010\2012\2013\2014\2043\FE63\FF0D'),
         '--------'
       ) like '%19663-01%'
```

Or you can update your data to try to normalise it to a single hyphen type:

```sql
UPDATE casemt
SET   indcase  = TRANSLATE(
                   indcase,
                   UNISTR('\1806\2010\2012\2013\2014\2043\FE63\FF0D'),
                   '--------'
                 )
WHERE indcase <> TRANSLATE(
                   indcase,
                   UNISTR('\1806\2010\2012\2013\2014\2043\FE63\FF0D'),
                   '--------'
                 );
```

and then your hyphens will be the ASCII hyphen and not a hyphen from the extended character set and then you can use:

```sql
SELECT caseid,
       indcase
FROM   casemt
WHERE  indcase LIKE '%19663-01%'
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=51dcf731f61e1f741e15e9cf801ede72)*

Answer (score 0):

Can you copy the '%19663-01%' exactly as it is in the query and check the result of the following:

```
SELECT DUMP('%19663-01%',16)
  FROM dual;
```

It should return this (considering your base is UTF8 encoded):

> Typ=96 Len=10: 25,31,39,36,36,33,2d,30,31,25

If the result is different you just have copied something with other encoding that transforms into some character that has no visual representation in your encoding.